# Compare multi-dynamic structure of pointers in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, winapi, structure

Basically, what I want to achieve is as follows;

I want to be able to compare a pointer-pointer to a structure block in memory without having to iterate through all of its values dynamically. I am working with an API-hook, so it is crucial to use a little "for loop iteration" as possible, better-yet, to use none.

Basically, assume I have a structure

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
  USHORT age;
  PCHAR username;
}
_myStruct, *__myStruct;
```

Then I initialize it like so

```
__myStruct *Pointer;
ZeroMemory(&Pointer, NULL);
```

Now just assume that the structure is filled with a group of values in each variable. Let's say I have defined a number 'x', and any given 'y' which is any given `Index` in the pointer to the structure.

```
for (int y = 0; y < SizeOfStructure; ++y)
  if (x == Pointer[y]->age)
    // do_something();
```

So, in this case, 'y' would be the iteration variable from a for-loop, but how can I do something along the line of:

```
if (memcmp(&Pointer, x) == 0)
  // do_something();
```

So that in this case I am not iterating the structure, and instead simply comparing all of its elements in memory at once? I would normally do a for-loop operation from with-in a `CRITICAL_SECTION` but either way it could still lead to a crash of the process. Is there any way I can do this in a safe manner as described above?

Comment: The only way I see to avoid iterating would be recursion, but I fear it is way more unstable than a loop...

Comment: By the way,  I don't get why iterations are supposed to crash the process?

Comment: `ZeroMemory(&Pointer, NULL);`. The 2nd argument of `ZeroMemory` is the length but you have NULL (= 0) here, therefore your call to `ZeroMemory`is a NOP. Why don't just write `Pointer = NULL`. `memcmp`requires 3 arguments, but you only provide two arguments. `memcmp` uses an iteration internally, I don't see why iterating is a problem. You want do compare n items, you must iterate over the n items.

Comment: `MichaelWalz` I wrote this on my phone. I wasn't beside an IDE at the time of writing this. Therefore, I didn't exactly have some "intelli-sense" plug-in to guide me ;)

`Kotshi` Well, I'm not sure if they would or wouldn't lead to a crash, but assume that the particular API that I'm hooking is called 1000 times/second - would this cause memory-overflow which could lead to a crash?

`On-the-side` So what you're saying is, the only thing I can do is iterate? That doesn't seem very flexible.

Comment: Your code and comments just make no sense to me. :| Perhaps some kind of language barrier, which is interesting in the case of code.

Comment: @NoOne049 let's say you want to compare 2 memory regions of 1 Mb each. Well someone has to go through all bytes of the two regions and do the comparision, there is no way around this.

Comment: @unwind - read the previous comment directed to `MichaelWalz`. Pardon my french.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, is there some kind of "safe" way of doing this that wouldn't abuse the memory usage in the application too much? At least so it's not noticeable, or lead to a crash?

Comment: @NoOne049 What is "abuse"? What is "the memory usage"? What is "too much"? Why would anything crash? You're not providing enough context for the question and comments to make sense. Comparing a few values 1,000 times/second doesn't have to take a lot of time on a typical modern computer.

Comment: @unwind Sorry for trailing you down a path of vines. I believe I simply wrote this question for one purpose - to refresh/clear my mind, and through these comments, that has been achieved. I apologize for over-encumbering your mind, while relieving mine. I believe this question has been answered. Thank-you all for your time!